# Want to sort only using columns 11 and 12 using the js provided

Tags: javascript, sorting

Pls check the  jsFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NWjR3/)       here,which sorts using the 3rd column. I have integrated it in my code which has 13 columns in the table. But I am not able to find out which part of the code to be changed in the javascript provided,so that only on click of the specific header,the table gets sorted. say, header 3 in this example, ( but I want it 11 in mine) Pls review the js and help me find out which LOC to change/edit

I am using it in MVC.
pls help me with the js code below,in finding which lines to be changed.

```
 var t = new SortableTable(document.getElementById('myTable1'), 100);

function SortableTable(tableEl) {

 this.tbody = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
 this.thead = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('thead');
 this.tfoot = tableEl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot');

 this.getInnerText = function (el) {
     if (typeof (el.textContent) != 'undefined') return el.textContent;
     if (typeof (el.innerText) != 'undefined') return el.innerText;
     if (typeof (el.innerHTML) == 'string') return el.innerHTML.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g, '');
 }

 this.getParent = function (el, pTagName) {
     if (el == null) return null;
     else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase()) return el;
     else return this.getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
 }

 this.sort = function (cell) {

     var column = cell.cellIndex;
     var itm = this.getInnerText(this.tbody[0].rows[1].cells[column]);
     var sortfn = this.sortCaseInsensitive;

     if (itm.match(/\d\d[-]+\d\d[-]+\d\d\d\d/)) sortfn = this.sortDate; // date format mm-dd-yyyy
     if (itm.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").match(/^[\d\.]+$/)) sortfn = this.sortNumeric;

     this.sortColumnIndex = column;

     var newRows = new Array();
     for (j = 0; j < this.tbody[0].rows.length; j++) {
         newRows[j] = this.tbody[0].rows[j];
     }

     newRows.sort(sortfn);

     if (cell.getAttribute("sortdir") == 'down') {
         newRows.reverse();
         cell.setAttribute('sortdir', 'up');
     } else {
         cell.setAttribute('sortdir', 'down');
     }

     for (i = 0; i < newRows.length; i++) {
         this.tbody[0].appendChild(newRows[i]);
     }

 }

 this.sortCaseInsensitive = function (a, b) {
     aa = thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]).toLowerCase();
     bb = thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]).toLowerCase();
     if (aa == bb) return 0;
     if (aa < bb) return -1;
     return 1;
 }

 this.sortDate = function (a, b) {
     aa = thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]);
     bb = thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]);
     date1 = aa.substr(6, 4) + aa.substr(3, 2) + aa.substr(0, 2);
     date2 = bb.substr(6, 4) + bb.substr(3, 2) + bb.substr(0, 2);
     if (date1 == date2) return 0;
     if (date1 < date2) return -1;
     return 1;
 }

 this.sortNumeric = function (a, b) {
     aa = parseFloat(thisObject.getInnerText(a.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]));
     if (isNaN(aa)) aa = 0;
     bb = parseFloat(thisObject.getInnerText(b.cells[thisObject.sortColumnIndex]));
     if (isNaN(bb)) bb = 0;
     return aa - bb;
 }

 // define variables
 var thisObject = this;
 var sortSection = this.thead;

 // constructor actions
 if (!(this.tbody && this.tbody[0].rows && this.tbody[0].rows.length > 0)) return;

 if (sortSection && sortSection[0].rows && sortSection[0].rows.length > 0) {
     var sortRow = sortSection[0].rows[0];
 } else {
     return;
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < sortRow.cells.length; i++) {
     sortRow.cells[i].sTable = this;
     sortRow.cells[i].onclick = function () {
         this.sTable.sort(this);
         return false;
     }
 }
```

}
Also I need to sort column with decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is sorting only numeric or date value fields so if your column number 11 will have numeric data then it will able to sort otherwise not.

Below code is cause in your function which will find numeric value from whole table and then sorting it.

```
if (itm.match(/\d\d[-]+\d\d[-]+\d\d\d\d/)) sortfn = this.sortDate; // date format mm-dd-yyyy
     if (itm.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").match(/^[\d\.]+$/)) sortfn = this.sortNumeric;
```

I try your code with decimal number too.

[Fiddle with decimal number](http://jsfiddle.net/NWjR3/2/)

**EDIT**:
Better way to sort
[Sorting array of float point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496898/sorting-array-of-float-point-numbers)

Comment: column 11 has decimal values... I guess that is the issue, but I am not able to sort it out.

Comment: Add your column no 11 values in your fiddle.

Comment: It does not work.. it sorts like this.. 0, 3.42, 5.2, 8.83, 5.29. It works well in the fiddle but not in VS MVC pjt

Comment: Add those values in fiddle please. and if its works fine in fiddle and not work in your project then there must be some issue in your project might you miss something.

Comment: can you suggest and send me a fiddle for any other better sorting methods to sort only specific columns

Comment: Sid, Can you suggest a better Js sorting method.. with a fiddle example pls

Comment: @user3118335 I had added link for sorting floating numbers

Comment: Add link for your project if you able?

Comment: Hey thanks Sid, I figured it out... I was missing a <th> in my mvc code... So stupid of me.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @user3118335 Please wattup or accept my answer so that it will help other too and you are welcome

Comment: I did try to..But I am in short of adequate reputation points.. Sorry Sid

Comment: Its ok and no need of sorry @user3118335