# How to check number is integer or float using jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

Actually we are using d3 with grails. there is scenario like we need to sort the given input according to integer, float and string.

I can check weather the input is number or string with `

```
if(typeof(d["colorField"])=='number'){
  L_KEY_NUMERIC = true;
}else{
   L_KEY_NUMERIC = true;
}
```

but this is failing for double value. double values are not getting sorted properly.

So, i need to check whether the key is double or integer using jquery.
currently I'am using sort() method which sorts for integer normally but not for double values. once i detect the key is double or float which sort method i need to use.

And how to sort float key via ascending order in jquery.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `d["colorField"] % 1 === 0` to check if key is number:

```
if(d["colorField"] % 1 === 0){
 //if number is integer 
 L_KEY_NUMERIC = true;
}else{
 //if number is float
 L_KEY_NUMERIC = true;
}
```

Comment: You have given answer to check number or float numbers.

Comment: if part to check number else part for not number

Comment: My question was different.  I know it number but after that how can I check key is integer number or float number.

Comment: that is what it does. if its integer, it will go in if part for float it will go in else part.

Comment: Thanks. For quick response will check now.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to sort float numbers in ascending order using jquery.

Comment: @PradeepSam: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18496997/1719752

Comment: Hi Milind please can you tell me how can i check a string is date or not. d["colorField"] has values ["1/10/1978 0:00",  "2/3/1988 0"] now this is not working if(isNaN(date)){
   alert(isNaN(date))
   stringIsDate ++;
  }

Comment: @PradeepSam: would be great if you can post new question with problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455261/how-to-sort-a-string-which-has-date-values-using-jquery/32456171#32456171 similar to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [parseFloat(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
e.g.
if (!isNan(parseFloat(string))){
  //your code here
}
```