# How to sort a string which has date values using jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, date

I need to check if a string is a date or not. If the string is a date then I need to sort it by ascending order.

I am getting values like

```
d["dates"] has values ["1/10/1978 0:00", "2/3/1988 0",.....,"1/10/1978 23:00"].
```

First I need to check whether it is date or not if its date I need to sort ascending order.

Any help is good.

I have tried this

```
var date = Date.parse(d["dates"]);
if(isNaN(date)){ console.log('not date')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure string is date:

```
 var sortedKey1 = new Array();
 var date = Date.parse(d["dates"]);
 sortedKey1 = d["dates"]
 if(isDate(date)){
     console.log('inside if of isDate(date)')
    KEY_IS_DATE = true;
 }
 function isDate(date) {
       return (new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(new Date(date)));

 }
```

For sorting according to date:

```
if(KEY_IS_DATE){
var sortedKey = sortedKey1.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime() 
});
console.log(sortedKey)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Iterate all array elements and do a date parse saving successful parse to another array.

[Working sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/2aj9f0a0/)

and sort can be done using various JS/Jquery Plugins.

```
var stringArry = ["1/10/1978 0:00", "2/3/1988 0", "1/10/1978 23:00"];
var dateArray = [];

$.each(stringArry, function (index, value) {
    var timestamp = Date.parse(value)
    if (isNaN(timestamp) == false) {
        var newDate = new Date(timestamp);
        dateArray.push(newDate);
    }
});

$.each(dateArray, function (index, value) {
    alert(index + ": " + value);
});
```